# How to apply cosine similarity loss function in unsupervised training?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In the Figure below is showed a simple deep learning architecture capable of learning embeddings for sentences. The training set is composed by sentence pairs `[[sentence_a],[sentence_b]]` that have the same semantics.

[image]

The objective is to fine-tune the embeddings of the sentences to be similar (since sentences in the pair have the same semantics). Consequently, a possible loss function would be `CosineSimilarity` loss.

`Encoder 1` and `Encoder 2` have the same definition:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class LSTMEncoder(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self,
                 units,  # dimensionality of the output space
                 input_dim,  # vocab of size
                 output_dim,  # embedding dimension
                 name='encoder',
                 **kwargs):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=output_dim)
        self.lstm = layers.LSTM(units=units)

    def call(self, inputs):
        emb = self.embedding(inputs)
        return self.lstm(emb)
```

And the SEntence Representations model `(SERModel)` looks like:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from source.layer.rnn_encoder import LSTMEncoder


class SERModel(tf.keras.Model):
    """
    Defines a SEntence Representations Model
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 units,  # dimensionality of the output space
                 input_dim,  # vocab of size
                 output_dim,  # embedding dimension
                 name='SEntence Representations Model',
                 **kwargs):
        super(SERModel, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.encoder = LSTMEncoder(units=units, input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=output_dim)

    def call(self, inputs):
        sentence_a, sentence_b = inputs
        return self.encoder(sentence_a), self.encoder(sentence_b)
```

To train the model one can simply do as shown next:

```py
from source.model.SERModel import SERModel
import tensorflow as tf


def run_test():

    # load train data
    train_data = load_data()

    ser = SERModel(units=128, input_dim=10000, output_dim=64)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

    ser.compile(optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity())
    ser.fit(train_data, epochs=3, batch_size=64)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test()
```

At this point is where I need help. The loss requires `y_true` and `y_pred`, but as can be seen, this is unsupervised training and there is no `y_true`. So, would you have an approach that would allow me to train the above architecture using `CosineSimilarity` loss?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the task into a supervised setting in the following way.

In your training data, `[[sentence_a],[sentence_b]]` is paired and has the same semantics. In this case, the cosine similarity is **1**, this is your `y_true`.

Besides, you also need unpaired samples because their cosine similarity is **0**. To generate unpaired samples, there is a simple way to do it. Shift `sentence_b` by one offset. That is,

```
[
[sentence_a_1, sentence_b_2],
[sentence_a_2, sentence_b_3],
[sentence_a_3, sentence_b_4],
]
```

So, now you have positive samples (your training data) and manually generated negative samples (shifted one). You can train your model in a supervised way.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about this, so will `sentence a` becomes x-train and `sentence b` becomes y-train, is that what you meant?

Comment: (or) Are you suggesting to convert it into a binary classification, that is positive pairs will have label 1 and negative pairs will have label 0, is that what you meant?

Comment: @user_12 the latter one is what I mean. Formulate this problem as a binary classification problem. We can generate positive and negative pairs respectively, and then train a classifier to predict whether a pair is positive or negative. By this way, hopefully we can learn meaningful sentence/word embeddings.